# Convert ISO 8601 week to American-formatted date

Tags: datetime, vba, ms-access

Requirements:

> Implement a function that, given a standard date and an indicator
> whether or not the output should be in american standard (weeks start
> on sundays, the first week of the year is the week containing the
> first day of the year) or in ISO8601 standard (weeks start on mondays,
> the first week of the year is the week containing the first thursday
> of the year) outputs the calendar week and year of the input date in
> the following format as a string.
>
> ```
> [calendar week] / [year]
> ```

Further requirements:

- camelCase is to be used for function names
- variables are to be underscore-seperated / lower_snake_case
- option explicit is mandatory

This is my implementation:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function convertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek(input_date As Date, mode As Integer) As String

Dim week As String
Dim year As String
If mode = 0 Then 'mode 0 = standard american timekeeping
    week = CStr(DatePart("ww", input_date, vbSunday, vbFirstJan1))
    year = CStr(DatePart("yyyy", input_date, vbSunday, vbFirstJan1))
ElseIf mode = 1 Then 'mode 1 = ISO8601 business timekeeping
   'using the thursday in the given week instead for calculation to avoid the datepart leap year bug
    week = CStr(DatePart("ww", input_date - Weekday(input_date, vbMonday) + 4, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays))
    year = CStr(DatePart("yyyy", input_date - Weekday(input_date, vbMonday) + 4, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays))
Else
    convertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek = "error"
    Debug.Print ("function convertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek called with invalid parameter mode " & mode)
    Exit Function
End If

convertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek = week & " / " & year

End Function
```

Runs fine from what I've tested (a lot of dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> convertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek = "error"
> Debug.Print ("function convertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek called with invalid parameter mode " & mode)
> ```

Bad idea. A bad function call involving invalid parameters is a programming bug, and should be a serious run-time error that takes down the whole thing. By returning a `String` you're forcing the caller to systematically verify that it's not getting the `"error"` magic string literal.

The function has one job. If it can't do it, it *should* blow up: there's a run-time error *specifically* for this:

```
Err.Raise 5, "ConvertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek", _
             "Invalid 'mode' parameter value: " & mode
```

Run-time error 5 is essentially your `ArgumentException`. If I consume your function and pass an invalid parameter, I'm *expecting* that error to be raised.

But what's that `mode` anyway?

```
Public Function convertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek(input_date As Date, mode As Integer) As String
```

From the signature, I've no idea. [Seriously] consider using an enum instead:

```
Public Enum WeekFormattingMode
    WFM_AmericanStandard
    WFM_ISO8601
End Enum
```

And now your signature can be (note, member names should be `PascalCase`):

```
Public Function ConvertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek(input_date As Date, mode As WeekFormattingMode) As String
```

Now the caller gets auto-completion when calling the function, and has to work very hard to supply an invalid parameter value.

This also eliminates magic constants in your implementation, *and* replaces the otherwise needed comments, which makes the code more self-descriptive:

```
Select Case mode
    Case WFM_AmericanStandard
        'handle American Standard formatting

    Case WFM_ISO8601
        'handle ISO-8601 formatting

    Case Else
        Err.Raise 5, "ConvertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek", _
                     "An invalid 'mode' parameter was supplied"
End Select
```

The parameters are implicitly passed `ByRef`, but they're not assigned and the caller doesn't need to use them - they're really read-only inputs that the function needs in order to work with; such parameters should be passed `ByVal`.

I don't agree with all your naming conventions, but as long as it's consistent, it should be good. I like that you're not using the very commonly abused *Systems Hungarian* notation. `Option Explicit` shouldn't be part of a *convention* though - it should be mandatory for any VBA code that isn't toy code - and heck, even toy code should have it.

Since you're using underscores in identifiers, I need to mention that it's important that this convention isn't applied to member names, especially public ones. This is simple code and there's no harm, but in more complex object-oriented code, an underscore in a procedure name can mean code that can't compile: VBA is reserving the underscore for a very specific meaning in member names.

---

I like that your function is *pure*, and therefore easily testable. But where are the tests?

With [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (a free, open-source VBE add-in I'm working on with a bunch of fellow VBA reviewers) you could document your requirements - and have tests that you can run anytime you make a change, as simple as this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'@TestModule
'@Folder("Tests")

Private Assert As New Rubberduck.AssertClass

'@TestMethod
Public Sub AmericanStandardOutputContainsSlashSpacer()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    Const splitter As String = " / "
    Dim actual As String

    actual = ConvertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek(Date, WFM_AmericanStandard)
    Assert.IsTrue InStr(expected, splitter) > 0

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

And so on:

- ISO standard weeks start on Monday
- American standard weeks start on Sunday
- ...

Every part of the specifications should have at least one test that covers it. And then you'll want tests to document behavior for invalid inputs, too:

```
'@TestMethod
Public Sub RaisesErrorGivenInvalidMode()
    Const ExpectedError As Long = 5
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    Const InvalidMode As Long = -1
    If InvalidMode = WFM_AmericanStandard Or InvalidMode = WFM_ISO8601 Then
        Assert.Inconclusive "InvalidMode must be an invalid parameter value."
    End If

    Dim actual As String
    actual = ConvertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek(Now, InvalidMode)

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = ExpectedError Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If
End Sub
```

Arguably, that "mode" parameter indicates that the function is doing too many things. If you split it into `FormatDateAmericanStandard` and `FormatDateISO8601` there would be no ambiguity whatsoever about how a date is formatted when you look at the calling code. Compare to:

```
foo = convertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek(someDate, 0)
```

Is `foo` formatted per the American standard or ISO-8601? The enum certainly helps, but then if I have to pick between this:

```
foo = ConvertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek(someDate, WFM_AmericanStandard)
bar = ConvertDateToFormattedCalendarWeek(someDate, WFM_ISO8601)
```

And this:

```
foo = FormatDateAmericanStandard(someDate)
bar = FormatDateISO8601(someDate)
```

I pick the latter without hesitation - note how it completely eliminates the whole discussion about raising an error vs. returning `"error"`, and eliminates the need to test/document what happens given an invalid `mode` parameter. And it makes the code much more explicit and self-descriptive, too.

A note about the name: you're not "converting a date" - you're "formatting a date" per a specified standard; I'd make the function name start with `FormatDate`.